# How can I help killing IE6?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

I'm fed-up supporting all the strange behaviors of the IE6 browser, so I'm wondering how, as a web developer, can I help killing IE6.

Should I just stop supporting it? I think there is still a big mass of pepole that use it for various reasons.

Maybe show IE6 users a special message that asks them to upgrade and hope it would help? (does it help?)

Any better ideas?

Comment: You can't. It's the main reason I don't much care for web-dev.

Comment: I have seen a blog which throws JS alert on each page load with rant about IE6. :)

Comment: Why kill something that's already dieing, some republicans might be offended ;)

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good idea if I do want people to use my site... :-)

Comment: Are you ready to loose clients? Because if that is me and some guy tells me to upgrade... why should I?

Comment: @Zyphrax: to help it to die fast

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611/ie6-to-support-or-not-to-support
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744216/save-me-from-ie6
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710905/why-are-people-still-using-ie6

Comment: @Zyphrax - its dieing for too long. why not help it to die faster?

Comment: @Rich Seller - this is not about supporting IE6.

Comment: No, but the referenced questions explain why it refuses to die

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IMHO one of the best ways to do this is to provide IE6 users a complete but downgraded version of your site.

Most companies can't afford to just deny access to the swathes of people who use IE6, and of course [users don't read messages](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/01/54734.aspx), so just denying access to IE6 users won't work.

In addition to this many users don't have the ability to choose a different browser because of their network's group policy.

So I think the best you can do is give a (maybe deliberately) downgraded experience (not AJAX, simpler interface) and try to make it clear that this would be better if you were on a more modern browser. This is what GMail does, of course.

The important thing is to make sure the IE6 version still works and doesn't crash or render hideously. IE6 users will see that and think 'Oh, that website doesn't work, I won't visit there again.'

This should spur people to ask their IT department to upgrade.

It's not perfect, but then I doubt any method is.

**Edit: Take a look at [this blog post](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2008/08/18/why-i-am-no-longer-supporting-ie6.aspx), basically says what I've said**

Answer (score 3):

First of all keep in mind that [IE6 usage primarily originates from office](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/06/state_of_the_br_1.html)(the place, not the software) users. If your site targets home users and not office users, you might consider dropping IE6 support.

Other than that there are a ton of initiatives. A few examples:

- http://www.stoplivinginthepast.com/
- http://www.stopie6.org/
- http://idroppedie6.com/
- http://www.stopie6.com/

Answer (score 2):

I use IE 6 at work- it is out of my control (I can't just install other browsers- well actually I can, but other uses who don't have admin right can't). Maybe you should learn to live with the fact that IE 6 is still used heavily in corporate environments and there is not a lot you can do about it, unless you wish to alienate a certain user base.

Comment: Think that all big sites should help IE6 to die, and corporates should learn to live with ability to update software at least once in some years and at least from a security point.

Comment: You (or rather the other uses who don't have admin rights) have my sympathy.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the upgrade notice from http://ie6update.com/ to your site.  However, you need to consider that many users are not on IE6 by choice and have no power to upgrade their browser.

Answer (score 2):

If you work for a paying client then you're out of luck, your only option is to try to educate him and hope he's an understanding type.

As for the public sites, well, just drop it. I haven't seen IE6 since two or maybe three years on my PC and I consider that enough to bury it.

You may however wish to display a message to the user, but not saying he's using an outdated browser but something with more psychological touch: "This page looks broken to you? This maybe because your browser is broken. Wish it to be fixed? Get an update.".

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding the css provided on http://www.ie6nomore.com/ to your web pages. It's a friendly little message that tells the users to upgrade :)

Answer (score 0):

I make sure that all my sites still "work" fully in IE6, but it doesn't bother me if there are some display issues. For example, things may not line up perfectly, or some non-essential javascript might not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in most corporate environments, IE6 is still the standard browser. This will slowly erode in the future, when Vista/Win7 will replace XP as the most common OS. Before that I see little chance of IT departments voluntarily rolling out IE7 or 8 when there is no clear need to do so (*don't fix it if it ain't broken*).

It would need at least one of the big guys (Google, Amazon, Yahoo...) to push IE6 out by not supporting it any longer. Since this will reduce their number of potential customers in the short run, they are unlikely to do so.
You have to decide for yourself if the potential customer loss for you is worth the effort saved if you don't support it any longer.

If you decide to not support it any more, give your users a short message about this (maybe like the notification bar here in SO?), together with a link to a more elaborate explanation *why* you decided this.

That being said, I just wish everybody would stop supporting IE6 **now**.

Comment: More and more big players are dropping IE6
Google: http://www.tgdaily.com/content/view/40785/140/
http://blog.wired.com/business/2009/02/norwegian-websi.html
http://37signals.blogs.com/products/2008/07/basecamp-phasin.html
http://www.usabilitypost.com/2008/09/05/drop-ie6-support-give-people-a-reason-to-upgrade/
http://blogs.salesforce.com/user_experience/2008/06/salesforce-and.html

Comment: Right, but the standard google search still works in IE6. Unfortunately...

Comment: Also, Facebook and Googlemail both display messages to users on IE6 regarding its lack of functionality; so it seems they're trying at least.